# Remove Pattern at Beginning of String but not at End

Tags: r, regex, string, data-cleaning

I have a list of schools, but some of them are ranked. I want to remove the rank of the schools (at the beginning of the string). When the school is ranked, it looks like this:

```
(3) Trinity
```

However, there are some schools that have parentheses at the end of their names, like this:

```
Concordia (Minn.)
```

So I don't want to remove the parenthesis if it is at the end of a string.

I'm not quite sure how to do this, but I'm assuming I'll need regex.

To get my data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

page_num <- seq(4, 16, by = 1) %>%
  paste("/", sep = "") %>%
  {page_num[-10]}

site <- paste("http://www.uscho.com/scoreboard/division-iii 
               men/20172018/list-", page_num, sep = "")

get_opponent <- function(x) {

  read_html(site[x]) %>%
    html_nodes("td:nth-child(2)") %>%
    html_text()

}

opponents <- map(seq(1, length(page_num)), get_opponent) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  tibble()

opponents
```

Comment: Visit `regex101.com` if you want to experiment with regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` here, with the following pattern^

```
^\s*\(\d+\)\s*(.*)
```

This matches a leading rank, with possible whitespace before and after it, then it matches and *captures* the remainder of the string.  It then replaces the string with the remainder.

```
x <- "(3) Trinity"
result <- sub("^\\s*\\(\\d+\\)\\s*(.*)", "\\1", x)
result

[1] "Trinity"
```

### Demo

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response. Wish I could actually understand the regex code here, but it greatly helps nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `sub` is

```
x <- c("(3) Trinity", "Concordia (Minn.)")
sub("^\\(.*\\)", "", x)

#[1] " Trinity"          "Concordia (Minn.)"
```

Replace everything which is inside round brackets at the beginning of the string.

Comment: That unescaped parenthesis just looks too weird to me, but otherwise +1.